# How do I adjust the left margin on parameters in ReSharper/VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-cleanup, resharper-5.1

This is silly, but when I have something like this

```
SomethingStupid.Whatever(string a, string b, string c);
```

And then I break them off like this:

```
SomethingStupid.Whatever(string a,
     string b,
     string c);
```

My code cleanup moves them to that position, when I'd like to see them here:

```
SomethingStupid.Whatever(string a,
                         string b,
                         string c);
```

For the life of me I can't figure out where this setting exists, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the setting at `ReSharper -> Options -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other -> Align Multiline Constructs -> Method Parameters`. Enabling the option will line up you multiline method parameters with each other as you want.

Comment: Does not work when we have methods that expects for expressions of type: `Expression<Func<>>`. Do you know if is there any feature to fix it?